# AS3 Shared Object as a Variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, shared-objects

I'm sure this is a very basic question, but I'm just wondering if it's possible to create shared object and name it after a string variable.

For Example:

```
var newvariable:Number = 0;

so.data.newvariable.toString(); = ??
```

Now I know that with the above example /\ there are easier ways around it, but I really need to find out alternative methods so I can actually name the shared object after the variable. Really appreciate this!

Comment: Dont mind the semicolon /\

Comment: variable names are irrelevant, you need a better understanding of coding and Flash coding in general. What you really care about is the value a variable point to, not the variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array access](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#array_access) brackets to create dynamic property names from variables:

```
var count:int = 0;
so.data["newvariable" + count] = "foo";
```